# input в телеграм бота, как реализовать

Tags: python-3.x

Бот должен узнать два числа, которые введу я ему сам, а потом создать переменные с этими значениями
num = 1 число,
prg = 2 число,
python, telebot

Comment: не проще добавить боту функцию eval, которая бы выполняла любой введенный вами после определенной команды код языка питон?